# Is this set dense in $[0, u]$ assuming $y$ is irrational?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, euclidean-geometry

Let $l$ in $[0,1)$ and $r$ in $(1, \infty)$. Fix $x$ in $[0, u] \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and define
$$
P(x) = \{l^nr^mx: n,m \in \mathbb{N}\,\,\mbox{s.t.}\,\, l^n r^m x \leq u\}
$$
to be the set of points in $[0,u]$ obtained from $x$ by moving $n$ times to the left and $m$ times to the right (with magnitudes given by $l$ and $r$). Write $l=\frac{1}{r^y}$ for some $y$.

> Assuming $y$ is irrational, is $P(x)$ dense in $[0,u]$?

My intuition is that the answer is yes (note: this would not be true in general if $y$ were rational)

This seems related to various known results (in billiard paths, number theory, etc.), but I can't put the pieces together…

Thanks for your help.

Comment: No, the set is not dense in general. Take l=1/2 and m=2 for example.

Comment: I believe the previous comment meant to say $r=2$, but it's right, it is not dense in general.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Do you know if it is dense when $y$ is irrational?

Comment: Yes, then it is dense all right.

Comment: @IvanNeretin, is it an existing result or just trivial?

Comment: I don't know exactly what counts as trivial for you. How about this: if $\alpha$ is irrational, then the set of $\{n\cdot\alpha\}$ (that is, fractional parts of $n\cdot\alpha,n\in\mathbb N$) is dense in $[0,1]$? This is an existing result, and yours follows from it, well, kinda trivially.

Comment: @IvanNeretin, Thanks for pointing out Kronecker's theorem! This is it.

Answer (score 0):

We must add the requirement that $l^jr^k=1$ only if $j=k=0$.

One can also note that one can cut away some distractions. For one we need not limit us to the interval $[0,u]$. If you drop that restriction you can prove it to be dense in $\mathbb R^+$ and denseness to the restriction follows.

To scetch one possible proof is to first construct a convergent series of $l^jr^k$ by making it bounded (this is done by succesively multiplying with $l$ or $r$ depending on the value of the last element).

This series is a cauchy sequence of distinct elements which means that by the way the series is constructed we can find a $l^jr^k$ arbitrarily close to $1$.

We then can use that fact to see that we can get arbitrarily close to any point since we always can find points on either side and can then multiply with the constructed $l^jr^k$ until we're close enough (eventually one passes the point and since the step passing it is arbitrarily small we're arbitrarily near).

Comment: Thanks Skyking! This is a clever alternative to using Kronecker's result.